# How to get count of child node for each parent element

Tags: css, xml, xslt

```
Source XML 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <parent1>
        <child1>P1-Child-01</child1>
        <child2>P1-Child-02</child2>
    </parent1>
    <parent2>
        <child3>P2-Child-03</child3>
        <child4>P2-Child-04</child4>
        <child5>P2-Child-05</child5>
    </parent2>
    <parent3>
        <child6>P2-Child-03</child6>
        <child7>P2-Child-04</child7>
    </parent3>
</root>

Required output 
<root>
    <parent1>
        <cld1>P1-Child-01</cld1>
        <cld2>P1-Child-02</cld2>
    </parent1>
    <parent2>
        <cld3>P2-Child-03</cld3>
        <cld4>P2-Child-04</cld4>
    </parent2>
</root>
```

i tried creating an XSLT with below logic:
1. It will get the number of parent elements 
2. based on that for each parent element i want to get the number of child elements and based on string concat(chld,$index) i want to create new elements 
i.e
replacing

```
    <child1>P1-Child-01</child1>
```

with
     `<cld4>P2-Child-04</cld4>`

but i stuck no how to get the count of child elements for each parent 
current Xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:call-template name="parentforloop"></xsl:call-template>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="parentforloop" > 
    <xsl:param name="index" select ="1" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="count(/*/*)"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentName" select="concat('parent',$index)"/>

            <xsl:element name="{concat('parent',$index )}">

            </xsl:element>


        <xsl:if test="not($index=$total)">
            <xsl:call-template name="parentforloop">
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index+1"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help

thank You

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. In the output why does parent2 have only two child nodes? Where does their name come from? Are things like these just sample text values `P1-Child-01` - if yes, please chose neural names like *banana, tomato*.

Comment: can you please refer the source XML and the required output. P1-Child-01 are dummy values. the parent tags can take value as <parent1> till <parentn> i.e 'n' number of values similary for child tags in the source Xml can take values from 1...to n i.e <child1> ...to <childn>

Comment: I fail to see, as well, how you get from your input to your output.

Comment: It isn't clear what was the rule to get from the 'source XML' int 'Required output'. Why `parent3` and `child5` don't have corresponding elements in the output?

Comment: @Brijesh Can you please edit your post and make the examples more expressive/less special. I still don't know for example why does `parent2` have only two children or where do their names come from.

Comment: Apologies ..i am closing this question as .. the source XML format was wrong .. with the new source XMl i am able  to achive the desired results..Thank You